# Sales console and CTI integration using sales cloud

Tags: profile, permission-sets, cti, userlicense

Can we use CTI integration and sales console by using Sales cloud?
Is it necessary to to have service cloud user license? OR **only** Sales cloud user license can be used to have CTI integration and sales console? How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Service cloud license is required to integrate CTI in sales console. Please contact your account executive to setup sales console in your organization.